# Odd, odd error regarding Java / Eclipse / Windowbuilder not getting values?

Tags: java, swing, label, awt, windowbuilder

I have  a really odd problem.. The "getValueAt" method return values apart from the frequency one - it returns null. I do not understand why as the table as a method in it. Does anyone one know why?

```
JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add ");
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            lblWeSuggestThe.setText(woooord);;
            id.add(table_1.getValueAt(0,0)+"");
            forename.add(table_1.getValueAt(0,1)+"");
            surname.add(table_1.getValueAt(0,2)+"");
            address.add(table_1.getValueAt(0,3)+"");
            frequency.add(table_1.getValueAt(0,4)+"");
            JLabel lblWeSuggestThe = new JLabel("We suggest the use of ID " + (id.size() + 1) + ".");
                try {
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter ("southbank.csv", true);
                    fw.write("\n" + table_1.getValueAt(0,0) + "," +table_1.getValueAt(0,1) + "," +table_1.getValueAt(0,2) + "," +table_1.getValueAt(0,3) + "," +table_1.getValueAt(0,4) +"");
                fw.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {

                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
```

*

Comment: are you sure you've defined table_1 true ?

Comment: Yeah, I just found the error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To those in future with this problem, you must press enter once the final value has been entered OR click on a different column from the data you are entering as the data does not get SET.

For example, click the fourth entry after entering the fifth and final entry.